# Attempting to Write Tuple to Flink Kafka sink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to write a streaming application that both reads from and writes to Kafka. I currently have this but I have to toString my tuple class.

```scala
object StreamingJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")

    val consumer = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))

    val counts = consumer.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .sum(1)

    val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer08[String](
      "localhost:9092",
      "my-topic",
      new SimpleStringSchema())

    counts.map(_.toString()).addSink(producer)

    env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton")
  }
}
```

The closest I could get to getting this working was the following but the FlinkKafkaProducer08 refuses to accept the type parameter as part of the constructor.

```scala
val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer08[(String, Int)](
  "localhost:9092",
  "my-topic",
  new TypeSerializerOutputFormat[(String, Int)])

counts.addSink(producer)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to write the tuples directly to my Kafka sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class approximately like this that serializes your tuples:

```
private class SerSchema extends SerializationSchema[Tuple2[String, Int]] {
  override def serialize(tuple2: Tuple2[String, Int]): Array[Byte] = ...
}
```